# R: Creating a Function to Randomly Replace Data from a Data Frame

Tags: r, function, random, data-manipulation, categorical-data

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data ("my_data"):

```
set.seed(123)


num_var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
num_var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
num_var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_4 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_5 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

factor_1 <- c("A","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("AA","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("AAAAA","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

id = 1:1000

my_data = data.frame(id,num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)


> head(my_data)
  id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  1  9.439524  5.021006  4.883963  8.496925  11.965498            B           AA          AAA         CCCC         AAAA
2  2  9.769823  4.800225 12.369379  6.722429  16.501132            B           AA          AAA         AAAA         AAAA
3  3 11.558708  9.910099  4.584108 -4.481653  16.710042            C           AA          BBB         AAAA         CCCC
4  4 10.070508  9.339124 22.192276  3.027154  -2.841578            B           CC          DDD         BBBB         AAAA
5  5 10.129288 -2.746714 11.741359 35.984902 -10.261096            B           AA          AAA         DDDD         DDDD
6  6 11.715065 15.202867  3.847317  9.625850  32.053261            B           AA          CCC         BBBB         EEEE
```

**My Question:** Given the above dataset, I am trying to create a function that (repeatedly) removes random rows from the above dataset in the following way:

- **Step 1:** The dataset has 10 variables - in Step 1, randomly select "n" of these variables ("n" has to be less than 10).
- **Step 2:** For the above "n" variables, if they are "factor", randomly select a subset (of size "m") of the levels for each of these factor variables. For each of the non-factor variables, split them randomly at a point between their minimum and their maximum (call this point "p").
- **Step 3:** Generate a random number between 0 and 1 (call this "r").
- **Step 4:** Select all rows identified in Step 2. For these rows, consider the columns that were not used in the logic condition. For these columns, there is a "r" percent probability that any element in these rows can be replaced with 0.
- **Step 5:** Repeat Step 1 - Step 4  for 10 times.

As an example, this would look like this:

- **Step 1:** Suppose n is randomly chosen as 4. 4 random variables are chosen : num_var_2, num_var_5, factor_var_3, factor_var_4
- **Step 2:** For num_var_2, a point at 7 is chosen. For num_var_5, a point at 19 is chosen. For factor_var_3, 2 are chosen levels : "BBB" and "CCC". For factor_var_4, 3 levels "AAAA", "DDDD", "EEEE".
- **Step 3:** A random number of 0.25 is chosen
- **Step 4:** `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE num_var_2 >7 &  num_var_5 > 19 & factor_var_3 = "BBB, CCC" & factor_var_4 = "AAAA, DDDD, EEEE"` . For each row in the unselected columns (num_var_1, num_var_3, num_var_4, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_5), each element in that row now has a 25% chance of being replaced with 0.
- **Step 5:** Repeat Step 1 - Step 4, 10 times. At some point, it is possible that a row will be selected that has already been replaced with a 0 in the past. This will make no difference as 0 replaced with 0 is still 0.

**Can someone please show me how to write a function that does this?**

Currently, I am trying to do this manually:

```
# 4 variables are selected
n = sample.int(10, 1)
[1] 4

# which 4 variables are selected (each number corresponds to their position):
sample.int(10, length(n))
[1] 6 2 1 4

num_var_1
num_var_2
num_var_4
factor_var_1

#select random points for the continuous variables

p1 <- runif(1, min(num_var_1), max(num_var_1))
p2 <- runif(1, min(num_var_2), max(num_var_2))
p4 <- runif(1, min(num_var_4), max(num_var_4))

#select random factor levels for the factor variable

nlevel = nlevels(factor_var_1)
nlevels = sample.int(nlevel, 1)
[1] 2

sample(factor_1, nlevels, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2))
[1] "A" "B"

#generate random probability number

r = runif(1,0,1)
[1] 0.4514667

#identify rows matching the above condition

identified_rows = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 > p1 & my_data$num_var_2 > p2 & my_data$num_var_4 > p4 & my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c("A", "B")), ]

> identified_rows
     id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4 num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
208 208  9.405383  15.53998  4.348425  29.87149  23.46945            B           CC          BBB         DDDD         DDDD
589 589 10.582991  18.84683  5.437036  31.53734  11.16494            B           BB          AAA         BBBB         CCCC
```

Now, for row 208, there is a `0.4514667` probability that the value in any of the remaining 6 columns (num_var_3, num_var_5, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5) will be replaced  0. For row 589, there is a  `0.4514667` probability that the value in any of the 6 remaining columns (num_var_3, num_var_5, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5) will be replaced with 0.

After this, I would again repeat this entire process another 9 times.

This is a very long way to do this - can someone please help me write a function that will make this faster (e.g. repeat this 100 times)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (I think). The following function implements the 5 step process you outlined above.

```
random_drop <- function(x) {
  # Randomly select variables
  which_vars <- names(x[, sort(sample(ncol(x), sample(ncol(x), 1)))])
  # Randomly select factor levels subset or generate continuous cutoff value
  cutoff_vals <- lapply(
    which_vars,
    function(i) {
      if (is.factor(x[[i]])) {
        return(sample(levels(x[[i]]), sample(nlevels(x[[i]]), 1)))
      }
      runif(1, min(x[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(x[[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
    }
  )
  names(cutoff_vals) <- which_vars
  # Create random prob value
  r <- runif(1,0,1)
  # Generate idx for which rows to select
  row_idx <- Reduce(
    `&`,
    lapply(
      which_vars,
      function(i) {
        if (is.factor(x[[i]])) {
          return(x[[i]] %in% cutoff_vals[[i]])
        }
        x[[i]] > cutoff_vals[[i]]
      }
    )
  )
  x_sub <- x[row_idx, !colnames(x) %in% which_vars, drop = FALSE]
  # With prob. 'r' fill row values in with '0'
  r_mat <- matrix(
    sample(
      c(TRUE, FALSE), 
      ncol(x_sub)*nrow(x_sub), 
      replace = TRUE, 
      prob = c(r, 1 - r)
    ),
    nrow = nrow(x_sub),
    ncol = ncol(x_sub)
  )
  x_sub[r_mat] <- 0
  x[row_idx, !colnames(x) %in% which_vars] <- x_sub
  return(x)
}
```

Then this function recursively will apply the function as many times as you wish.

```
random_drop_recurse <- function(x, n = 10) {
  if (n == 1) return(random_drop(x))
  random_drop_recurse(random_drop(x), n = n - 1)
}
```

Note: `0` is not a valid factor level so this function will generate warnings due to trying to replace factor values with `0` and will instead replace the factor values with `NA`.

Using a subset of your data supplied above, this is what it looks like running the function 10 and 100 times, respectively:

```
set.seed(123)

num_var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
num_var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
num_var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_4 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_5 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

factor_1 <- c("A","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("AA","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("AAAAA","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

my_data = data.frame(num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)

random_drop <- function(x) {
  # Randomly select variables
  which_vars <- names(x[, sort(sample(ncol(x), sample(ncol(x), 1)))])
  # Randomly select factor levels subset or generate continuous cutoff value
  cutoff_vals <- lapply(
    which_vars,
    function(i) {
      if (is.factor(x[[i]])) {
        return(sample(levels(x[[i]]), sample(nlevels(x[[i]]), 1)))
      }
      runif(1, min(x[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), max(x[[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
    }
  )
  names(cutoff_vals) <- which_vars
  # Create random prob value
  r <- runif(1,0,1)
  # Generate idx for which rows to select
  row_idx <- Reduce(
    `&`,
    lapply(
      which_vars,
      function(i) {
        if (is.factor(x[[i]])) {
          return(x[[i]] %in% cutoff_vals[[i]])
        }
        x[[i]] > cutoff_vals[[i]]
      }
    )
  )
  x_sub <- x[row_idx, !colnames(x) %in% which_vars, drop = FALSE]
  # With prob. 'r' fill row values in with '0'
  r_mat <- matrix(
    sample(
      c(TRUE, FALSE), 
      ncol(x_sub)*nrow(x_sub), 
      replace = TRUE, 
      prob = c(r, 1 - r)
    ),
    nrow = nrow(x_sub),
    ncol = ncol(x_sub)
  )
  x_sub[r_mat] <- 0
  x[row_idx, !colnames(x) %in% which_vars] <- x_sub
  return(x)
}

random_drop_recurse <- function(x, n = 10) {
  if (n == 1) return(random_drop(x))
  random_drop_recurse(random_drop(x), n = n - 1)
}

suppressWarnings(
  head(
    random_drop_recurse(my_data[, c(1:3, 6:8)], 10),
    20
  )
)
#>    num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3
#> 1   9.439524  5.021006  4.883963            B           AA          AAA
#> 2   9.769823  4.800225 12.369379            B           AA          AAA
#> 3  11.558708  9.910099  0.000000            C           AA          BBB
#> 4  10.070508  9.339124 22.192276            B           CC          DDD
#> 5  10.129288 -2.746714 11.741359            B           AA          AAA
#> 6  11.715065 15.202867  3.847317         <NA>           AA          CCC
#> 7  10.460916 11.248629 -8.068930            C           CC         <NA>
#> 8   8.734939 22.081037  0.000000            C           AA          BBB
#> 9   9.313147 13.425991 30.460189            C           AA          BBB
#> 10  9.554338  7.765203  4.392376            B           AA          AAA
#> 11 11.224082 23.986956  1.640007            A         <NA>          AAA
#> 12 10.359814 24.161130 16.529475            A           AA          AAA
#> 13  0.000000  3.906441  0.000000            A           CC         <NA>
#> 14 10.110683 12.345160 17.516291            B           CC          AAA
#> 15  9.444159  8.943765  7.220249            A           AA          DDD
#> 16 11.786913 10.935256 21.226542            B           CC          DDD
#> 17 10.497850 11.137714 -1.726089            B           AA          AAA
#> 18  8.033383  3.690498  9.511232            B           CC          CCC
#> 19 10.701356 11.427948  2.958597            B           BB          AAA
#> 20  9.527209 18.746237 16.807586            C           AA          BBB

suppressWarnings(
  head(
    random_drop_recurse(my_data[, c(1:3, 6:8)], 100),
    20
  )
)
#>    num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3
#> 1   9.439524   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 2   9.769823   0.00000 12.369379            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 3  11.558708   0.00000  0.000000         <NA>         <NA>          BBB
#> 4  10.070508   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 5  10.129288   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 6  11.715065   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 7  10.460916   0.00000  0.000000            C         <NA>         <NA>
#> 8   0.000000  22.08104  0.000000         <NA>           AA         <NA>
#> 9   9.313147   0.00000  0.000000            C         <NA>         <NA>
#> 10  0.000000   0.00000  0.000000            B           AA          AAA
#> 11 11.224082   0.00000  0.000000         <NA>         <NA>          AAA
#> 12 10.359814   0.00000  0.000000            A         <NA>         <NA>
#> 13 10.400771   0.00000  0.000000            A         <NA>         <NA>
#> 14 10.110683   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 15  9.444159   0.00000  0.000000            A         <NA>         <NA>
#> 16 11.786913   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 17 10.497850   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 18  8.033383   0.00000  0.000000            B         <NA>         <NA>
#> 19  0.000000   0.00000  2.958597            B           BB          AAA
#> 20  9.527209   0.00000  0.000000            C         <NA>          BBB
```

Comment: @ Daniel Molitor: Thank you so much for your answer! Just a question, in the example, why did you use  random_drop_recurse(my_data[, c(1:3, 6:8)], 10) instead of  random_drop_recurse(my_data, 10)?

Comment: Is there also a way to see which combination of variables were replaced with 0 at each iteration? For example, is it possible to print a list containing the combinations of variable being replaced with 0?

Comment: @stats555 No problem. That was purely so that I could show you the output of the function nicely (without it getting too wide)!

Comment: @ Daniel Molitor: Thank you so much! Should I post another question where I ask how to find out which combinations of variables are being replaced with 0 at each iteration?

Comment: As far as getting the replacement indexes at each step, that is definitely possible but would create a few extra steps. In `random_drop` you'd probably want to do something like return both the dataframe as well as the indices in a list and then in `random_drop_recurse` at each step you could append the indices to a larger list that shows the dropped indices at each step. I'll think about this and see if I can add it to the existing answer.

Comment: @ Daniel Molitor: Thank you for your reply! Please let me know if you would like me to create a new question about this if necessary.

Comment: @stats555 that would be great; I added a couple lines of code that do what you're looking for and that'll be easier to illustrate in a new question I think.

Comment: @ Daniel Molitor: I have posted the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483695/r-recording-the-index-iterations-of-a-function . Thank you so much!