# R: Reading SQL style Statements Stored in a Data Frame

Tags: r, select, where-clause, rows, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

**Part 1:**  I have the following data set ("my_data"):

```
num_var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
num_var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
num_var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_4 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_5 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

factor_1 <- c("A","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("AA","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("AAAAA","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

my_data = data.frame(id,num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)


> head(my_data)
  id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  1  9.439524  5.021006  4.883963  8.496925  11.965498            B           AA          AAA         CCCC         AAAA
2  2  9.769823  4.800225 12.369379  6.722429  16.501132            B           AA          AAA         AAAA         AAAA
3  3 11.558708  9.910099  4.584108 -4.481653  16.710042            C           AA          BBB         AAAA         CCCC
4  4 10.070508  9.339124 22.192276  3.027154  -2.841578            B           CC          DDD         BBBB         AAAA
5  5 10.129288 -2.746714 11.741359 35.984902 -10.261096            B           AA          AAA         DDDD         DDDD
6  6 11.715065 15.202867  3.847317  9.625850  32.053261            B           AA          CCC         BBBB         EEEE

> str(my_data)

'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ num_var_1   : num  10.25 10.3 12.75 9.18 9.74 ...
 $ num_var_2   : num  1.68 8.79 15.58 -2.52 8.39 ...
 $ num_var_3   : num  1.64 15.68 -3.24 7.8 6.44 ...
 $ num_var_4   : num  19.19 8.53 11.31 6.84 9.7 ...
 $ num_var_5   : num  4.912 14.25 -0.112 4.799 1.871 ...
 $ factor_var_1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ factor_var_2: Factor w/ 3 levels "AA","BB","CC": 1 3 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ factor_var_3: Factor w/ 4 levels "AAA","BBB","CCC",..: 3 2 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ factor_var_4: Factor w/ 5 levels "AAAA","BBBB",..: 4 1 4 1 4 2 1 5 1 2 ...
 $ factor_var_5: Factor w/ 5 levels "AAAA","BBBB",..: 5 2 3 2 3 2 4 1 4 4 ...

> summary(my_data)
       id           num_var_1        num_var_2        num_var_3        num_var_4         num_var_5       factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
 Min.   :   1.0   Min.   : 6.510   Min.   :-7.957   Min.   :-20.47   Min.   :-17.002   Min.   :-21.402   A:319        AA:531       AAA:529      AAAA:524     AAAA:380    
 1st Qu.: 250.8   1st Qu.: 9.302   1st Qu.: 6.480   1st Qu.:  3.38   1st Qu.:  3.586   1st Qu.:  2.753   B:477        BB:271       BBB:184      BBBB:173     BBBB:258    
 Median : 500.5   Median :10.025   Median :10.063   Median : 10.21   Median : 10.409   Median :  9.348   C:204        CC:198       CCC:200      CCCC: 97     CCCC:130    
 Mean   : 500.5   Mean   : 9.997   Mean   : 9.963   Mean   : 10.03   Mean   : 10.087   Mean   :  9.694                             DDD: 87      DDDD:125     DDDD:113    
 3rd Qu.: 750.2   3rd Qu.:10.713   3rd Qu.:13.234   3rd Qu.: 16.48   3rd Qu.: 17.114   3rd Qu.: 16.597                                          EEEE: 81     EEEE:119    
 Max.   :1000.0   Max.   :13.403   Max.   :26.731   Max.   : 44.68   Max.   : 42.056   Max.   : 43.102
```

**Part 2 :** I also have the following data frame (called "d") that contains a different logical condition on each row:

```
head(d)  

    iteration                                                                                                                                                                                        results
          1                                                                                                                                                 num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC"
          2         num_var_1 < 8.44, num_var_4 > 37.01, factor_var_1 = "A, B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, DDDD", factor_var_5 = "BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          3                                               num_var_1 < 9.70, num_var_2 < 19.75, num_var_3 < 35.03, num_var_4 > 20.12, num_var_5 < -6.67, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB"
          4                                                                                         num_var_4 > 31.51, num_var_5 < 4.49, factor_var_1 = "C", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          5                                                                                     num_var_4 < 23.87, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, DDD", factor_var_5 = "AAAA, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE"
          6                                                                                                                                     num_var_4 < 18.07, factor_var_5 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          7                                                                                                      num_var_3 < 9.19, num_var_4 < 13.21, num_var_5 < 14.59, factor_var_4 = "BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"
          8 num_var_1 > 11.07, num_var_3 > 8.17, num_var_4 < 23.00, num_var_5 < 35.93, factor_var_2 = "AA", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, DDD", factor_var_4 = "AAAA, BBBB, EEEE", factor_var_5 = "CCCC, EEEE"
          9                                                                               num_var_1 < 10.77, num_var_2 > 24.95, num_var_3 > 4.78, factor_var_2 = "CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"
        10                                                                                      num_var_2 > 2.65, factor_var_1 = "B, C", factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC", factor_var_3 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD"


> str(d)


'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ iteration: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ results  : chr  "num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = \"AA, BB, CC\"" "num_var_1 < 8.44, num_var_4 > 37.01, factor_var_1 = \"A, B, C\", factor_var_2 = \"AA, BB, CC\", factor_var_3 = "| __truncated__ "num_var_1 < 9.70, num_var_2 < 19.75, num_var_3 < 35.03, num_var_4 > 20.12, num_var_5 < -6.67, factor_var_2 = \""| __truncated__ "num_var_4 > 31.51, num_var_5 < 4.49, factor_var_1 = \"C\", factor_var_4 = \"AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE\"" ...
```

**My Question:**

I am trying to take select rows from "my_data" based on the logical statements stored within the rows of "d".  For example, I can do this manually:

```
# row 1 of "d" : num_var_5 > 29.80, factor_var_2 = "AA, BB, CC"

my_data_using_row1_of_d  = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_5 > 29.80 & my_data$factor_var_2  %in% c("AA", "BB", "CC") ), ]

# row 6 of "d" :  num_var_4 < 18.07, factor_var_5 = "AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, EEEE"

my_data_using_row6_of_d  = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_4 > 18.07 & my_data$factor_var_5  %in% c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "EEEE") ), ]

# row 1 and row 6 together:

row_1_and_row_6 = rbind(my_data_using_row1_of_d, my_data_using_row6_of_d)
```

**But is there a way to automatically take the logical conditions from different rows of "d" and use them to select rows from "my_data"?**

For example:

```
#pseduocode : 6th row, 2nd column of "d"
       my_data_using_row6_of_d  = my_data[which(d[6,2]) ), ]
```

Can someone please show me this?

Thanks!

**Note:** The data frame "d" is also available in this format ("d2") if it makes selecting rows easier:

```
> d2
   num_var_1 num_var_2  num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2    factor_var_3             factor_var_4             factor_var_5
1   8.251683 27.791314  30.525573  33.95768   2.388074            B         <NA>             AAA                     AAAA                     DDDD
2   9.012602        NA         NA        NA  20.236515            A        AA BB            <NA>                     <NA>                     BBBB
3         NA 16.778085  28.097324   5.69020         NA            B           BB     CCC DDD DDD                     <NA> AAAA BBBB CCCC CCCC CCCC
4  12.838667 -3.694075  13.411877  -2.20004         NA         <NA>     AA AA BB     AAA BBB CCC                     <NA> AAAA AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
5         NA        NA  11.922439  17.63757         NA          A B     AA AA BB            <NA>                AAAA AAAA                     BBBB
6  12.768595        NA  28.507646        NA         NA            C           AA     BBB DDD DDD      AAAA AAAA CCCC DDDD AAAA AAAA BBBB EEEE EEEE
7         NA        NA -20.424906        NA  20.147004         <NA>        AA AA            <NA> AAAA AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE                     <NA>
8         NA  6.299722   8.569485  24.82825 -17.715862         <NA>           BB AAA AAA BBB CCC                     <NA>                BBBB EEEE
9  10.846757        NA         NA        NA         NA        A B C     AA BB CC            <NA>                     <NA>                BBBB BBBB
10        NA  4.663916  22.335404        NA         NA        B B C        AA BB AAA AAA AAA DDD AAAA AAAA CCCC EEEE EEEE                     <NA>
```

**References:**

- [Simulating Random Draws From a "Hat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483731/simulating-random-draws-from-a-hat)
- [R: Creating a Function to Randomly Replace Data from a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477594/r-creating-a-function-to-randomly-replace-data-from-a-data-frame/70482748#70482748)

**EDIT** : Better "Readable" Formats of "d" and "d2" (these are not exact matches from the examples in the question, but the format is the same):

```
    #d
    
   d =  structure(list(iteration = 1:6, records = c("num_var_2 < 12.51, num_var_3 > 41.50, factor_var_1 = \"A, B\"", 
                                                "num_var_1 < 11.16, num_var_3 > 15.63, num_var_4 > -3.87, factor_var_2 = \"BB\", factor_var_4 = \"AAAA, BBBB, DDDD\"", 
                                                "num_var_1 < 9.87, num_var_2 < -1.32, num_var_3 > -5.54, num_var_4 > 24.09, num_var_5 < 3.28, factor_var_2 = \"AA, BB, CC\", factor_var_3 = \"CCC\"", 
                                                "num_var_1 > 9.72, num_var_2 > -1.93, num_var_3 < 43.27, num_var_4 < 32.11, num_var_5 > -12.77, factor_var_1 = \"B\", factor_var_2 = \"AA\", factor_var_4 = \"AAAA, BBBB, DDDD\", factor_var_5 = \"AAAA\"", 
                                                "num_var_1 > 10.51, num_var_2 > 13.61, num_var_3 > 22.14, num_var_4 < -2.75, factor_var_1 = \"A, B, C\", factor_var_3 = \"AAA\", factor_var_4 = \"BBBB, DDDD, EEEE\"", 
                                                "factor_var_1 = \"A, B, C\", factor_var_5 = \"BBBB, CCCC, EEEE\""
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

#d2

d2 = structure(list(num_var_1 = c(0, 9.76982251051672, 11.5587083141491, 
10.0705083914246, 10.1292877351609, 11.7150649868833, 0, 8.73493876539347, 
9.31314714810647, 9.55433802990004), num_var_2 = c(0, 4.80022478116903, 
9.91009879711669, 9.33912433571633, -2.74671387375216, 15.2028672785969, 
11.248628679926, 22.0810368657416, 13.4259911902555, 7.76520345519004
), num_var_3 = c(4.88396277810419, 12.3693787912763, 4.58410828378302, 
22.1922764704307, 0, 3.84731683903522, -8.06892964085328, 3.56318894103961, 
30.4601885213282, 4.39237578868935), num_var_4 = c(8.49692522135921, 
6.72242867213538, -4.48165290183992, 3.02715415448378, 0, 9.62584986365951, 
0, 8.15473501735272, 16.0982429616145, 9.47273191012025), num_var_5 = c(0, 
16.5011318866726, 0, -2.84157765132228, 0, 0, 0, 13.7564226018481, 
-1.92968518298101, 21.3254984181008), factor_var_1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), factor_var_2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, NA, 
3L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), class = "factor"), 
    factor_var_3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), class = "factor"), 
    factor_var_4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"
    ), class = "factor"), factor_var_5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AAAA", "BBBB", 
    "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please post a usable form of `d`? As is, it's a real chore to try to read in partial strings and such. (The gold-standard is `dput(x)`, listed in both of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3358272, [mcve].)

Comment: @ r2evans : thank you for your reply! I will fix this right now!

Comment: You'll need to (a) `strsplit(., ",")` each of your `results` values, then if a particular statement contains `=` then you'll need to (b) `strsplit(., ",")` *again* so that you can try to convert it to an `%in%` statement. After that conversion, iterate over each row's collection of conditional expressions with `eval(parse(..), envir=my_data)`. For example, see `eval(parse(text="cyl > 4"), envir = mtcars)`.

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you for your reply! I am still working on making a "usable form" of d!

Comment: @ r2evans: please see the edits, there is now a more usable version of "d". Thanks!